# problem with php zend api and definition of an enum with zend_register_internal_enum

Tags: php, c, api, zend-framework

the following code **fails** if shared library is loaded with `dl()`

```
...
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(phpmkkernel)
{
#if defined(ZTS) && defined(COMPILE_DL_PHPMKKERNEL)
  ZEND_TSRMLS_CACHE_UPDATE();
#endif

#if defined(ZTS)
...
#endif

  /* If you have INI entries, uncomment these lines
  REGISTER_INI_ENTRIES();
  */

  return LibMkKernel_MInit     (INIT_FUNC_ARGS_PASSTHRU)  ;
}


static ZEND_RESULT_CODE LibMkKernel_MInit (INIT_FUNC_ARGS) {
...
  MK(MkErrorE) = zend_register_internal_enum("PhpMsgque\\MkKernel\\MkErrorE", IS_LONG, NULL);
  zend_enum_add_case_cstr(MK(MkErrorE), "OK", OT_TMP_INT_OBJ(0));
  zend_enum_add_case_cstr(MK(MkErrorE), "CONTINUE", OT_TMP_INT_OBJ(1));
  zend_enum_add_case_cstr(MK(MkErrorE), "ERROR", OT_TMP_INT_OBJ(2));
...
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

the problem is an assert in `create_enum_case_ast`

```
ZEND_ASSERT(ZSTR_IS_INTERNED(class_name));
```

if shared library is loaded with `extension` in **php.ini** than it is fine

```
extension="..."
```

question: what I have to do ?